# Get UrlHelper in middleware with ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

How can I get UrlHelper in middleware.
I try as below but `actionContextAccessor.ActionContext` return null.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession();

    services
        .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie();

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
}
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var urlHelperFactory = context.RequestServices.GetService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
        var actionContextAccessor = context.RequestServices.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>();

        var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
        await next();
        // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 pipelines in your app. The ASP.NET core pipeline that you're hooking into. And the ASP.NET MVC pipeline which is set up by UseMvc. ActionContext is an MVC concept and that's why it's not available in the ASP.NET core pipeline. To hook into the MVC pipeline, you can use [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters).

Comment: Thank Hans, now I can add a filter at global scope.

Answer (score -2):

You can try adding it to the service container on the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` instead. You can do this like below:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //Service injection and setup
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
                services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(factory =>
                {
                    var actionContext = factory.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>()
                                               .ActionContext;
                    return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
                });

    //....

   // Build the intermediate service provider then return it
    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

You can then modify your `Configure()` method to receive `IServiceProvider` , you can get the instance of `UrlHelper` by then doing the following.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {

    //Code removed for brevity

    var urlHelper = serviceProvider.GetService<IUrlHelper>(); <-- helper instance

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

**Note**: Place this after the `services.Mvc()`

Comment: So, how I get UrlHelper, in middleware? I don't know how to use it, after add `services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(...)`

Comment: `actionContextAccessor.ActionContext` still return null, exception throw at line `return new UrlHelper(actionContext);`