# ASP.NET Core Middleware and URL Parsing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, middleware

Trying to add special endpoints to an ASP.NET Core MVC through a middleware.

In a `app.UseWhen`, I need to parse the request URL. In a Controller context, MVC does a great job extracting `userId` using the following template:

`GET http://contoso.com/users/{userId}/addresses`

How could this be cleanly done in a middleware where MVC Controller constructs aren't setup?

Bonus points if the answer helps figuring out if the address conforms to this pattern in the first place.

All I have on hand is a [DefaultHttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.defaulthttpcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get UrlHelper in middleware asp.net mvc core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531791/get-urlhelper-in-middleware-asp-net-mvc-core-2-0)

Comment: About to resort to using Uri.Segments... if nobody comes with a better answer by the next 24h, I will post this as a solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: Found a solution based on this post: https://blog.markvincze.com/matching-route-templates-manually-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution based on [Mark Vincze's blog](https://blog.markvincze.com/matching-route-templates-manually-in-asp-net-core/)

This method used to extract the the user id and work with it...

```
    private static void AddAddressesRoute(IApplicationBuilder app, RouteBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.MapVerb(
            HttpMethod.Get.Method,
            "users/{userId}/addresses",
            async context =>
            {
                var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
                var userId = routeData.Values["userId"];

                // userId available from here
            }
        );
    }
```

Should be initiated from an application builder extension method.

```
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAddresses(
        this IApplicationBuilder app
    )
    {
        RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder(app);

        AddAddressesRoute(app, builder);

        app.UseRouter(builder.Build());

        return app;
    }
```

Becomes a middleware that can be added to the Startup.Configure method just like this:

```
    app.UseAddresses()
```

It doesn't even interfere with MVC that still gets triggered if the route doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

`URL` parsing comes to play in `MVC` pipeline, not in `ASP.NET Core` one.

You might want to consider `MVC` [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) instead, which have access to routing context.

Comment: As far as I understand, filters are applied in controllers in MVC applications. I'd like to understand how this could help in a middleware context.

Comment: That is the point - in middleware context routing is kind of makes no sense as this part of handling supposed to happen in MVC part of the chain. So  you either need to use something apart from MVC which also can parse URL templates, or.. you are just trying what you are in wrong place, or wrong way - in this case most likely your architecture should be revised.

Comment: I would agree with you if all endpoints were coded by the same team, and even part of the same project. Thing is, the middleware endpoints are part of an abstraction that's meant to be reused. They can't be part of a controller, and will even be included in a nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the HttpContext from middleware and parse out key-value pairs from the query string but you can not access the path parameters via key-value.

For example:

You make a GET to the following controller via `http://contoso.com/api/users/5?zip=90210`:

```
 // GET api/users/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

Custom Middleware:

```
public class MyCustomMiddleware
{
    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {   
        // get full path from context request path
        var queryPath = context.Request.Path().ToString(); 
        // will return /api/users/5

        // get id from query string
        var queryStringId = context.Request.Query["zip"].ToString();
        // will return 90210
    }
}
```

There isn't any mapping from your Controller parameters to the HttpContext.

Comment: Thing is, the problem is about path values, not querystrings.